# JBoss force startup-load of lazy, passive or on-demand service

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

At the JBoss startup usually not all services are started.

```
10:44:19,160 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.1.5.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.19.Final-redhat-00001) started in 3594ms - Started 300 of 560 services (343 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

For debugging I want to force one service (the Keycloak-saml subsystem in my case) to be loaded on startup although it is lazy, passive or on-demand.

How can I do that with JBoss EAP 7?

Comment: You can add dependency elements to your module.xml file:

{code:xml}<module ...>

     <resources>

          ...

     </resources>

 

     <dependencies>

          <module name="org.jboss.as.web" />

     </dependencies>

</module>{code}

Comment: Will this force the module to load eagerly at startup?